# How to remove duplicate dictionary Objects from list

Tags: python

I want to remove the dictionary from the list which contains duplicate values

```
list = [{'data': 'sql_data'},{'data':'mongo_data'},{'data':'sql_data'}]

list = [{'data': 'sql_data'},{'data':'mongo_data'}]
```

Comment: You want to remove duplicate values, duplicate keys or duplicate dicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pandas, if it doesn't have nested dict

```
import pandas as pd
list = pd.DataFrame(list).drop_duplicates().to_dict(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sorted` with `set`:

```
import ast
print(sorted(map(ast.literal_eval,set(map(str,list))),key=list.index))
```

Or:

```
l=[]
for i in list:
    if i not in l:
        l.append(i)
```

Both Output:

```
[{'data': 'sql_data'},{'data':'mongo_data'}]
```

Comment: Ah, Wouldn't this now produce: `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`

Comment: @user5173426 Why?

Comment: @user5173426 forgot to rename list https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/9e836cca-81d9-4831-9674-647a84b40a63/?i=true

Answer (score 2):

```
s = [{'data': 'sql_data'},{'data':'mongo_data'},{'data':'sql_data'}]

new = []
for x in s:
    if x not in new: new.append(x)        
print(new)
```

OR

one-line:

```
print([i for n, i in enumerate(s) if i not in s[n + 1:]])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'data': 'sql_data'}, {'data': 'mongo_data'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works even when the key is not `'data'`:

```
import json

list = [{'data': 'sql_data'}, {'data': 'mongo_data'}, {'data': 'sql_data'}, {'user': 'admin'}, {'user': 'admin'}]
list_deduplicated = [json.loads(i) for i in set([json.dumps(j) for j in list])]
print(list_deduplicated)
```

The output will be:

```
[{'data': 'mongo_data'}, {'data': 'sql_data'}, {'user': 'admin'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `list comprehensions` to solve this -

```
my_list=[{'data': 'sql_data'},{'data':'mongo_data'},{'data':'sql_data'}]
unique_list = [e for i, e in enumerate(my_list) if my_list.index(e) == i ]
print(unique_list)
    [{'data': 'sql_data'}, {'data': 'mongo_data'}]
```